# Can we stub in Spring Boot Test, Mockito, or powerMock in similar way as with Wiremock

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, powermock, powermockito

Indeed Wiremock is very powerful as for as integration tests are concerned. I love the way Wiremock stub a `URL` response without the mutation of the beans (The way we do in mockito or powermock for Unit tests).

```
    @Mock
    SomeRepository someRepository; //Zombie mutation

    @Mock
    AnotherComponent anotherComponent; //mutation

    @InjectMocks
    SomeService someService; //mutation - This is the class we are unit testing
```

In the integration test I want all 3 layers are get tested and mock external dependency

```
                      +---> Repository -----> MySQL (I managed this with in-memory h2 database)
                      |
controller---> service 
                      | 
                      +---> Proxy ---------> Another REST service (some way to mock the call???)
```

Is it possible to do the same with Spring Boot Test, or mockito or powermock (as I am already using them and just don't want to add a new library to the project)

Here is how we do stubbing in Wiremock.

```
 service.stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/another/service/call"))
                .willReturn(jsonResponse(toJson(objResponse))));
```

> Above code means, in our test whenever an external service will
>   be called (http://example.com/another/service/call), it will be intercepted and the sample response will be
>   injected - and external call will not leave the system

A sample code

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class StubTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    private MockRestServiceServer server;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        server = MockRestServiceServer.bindTo(restTemplate).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testFakeLogin() throws Exception {
        String sampleResponse = stubSampleResponse();

        //Actual URL to test
        String result = mockMvc.perform(get("/s1/method1")
                .contentType("application/json"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();

        assertThat(result).isNotNull();
        assertThat(result).isEqualTo(sampleResponse);
    }

    private String stubSampleResponse() {

        String response = "Here is response";

        //URL to stub (this is in another service)
        server.expect(requestTo("/v1/s2/dependent-method"))
                .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
                .andRespond(withSuccess(response, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        return response;
    }
}
```

**Feign Client**

```
@FeignClient(value = "service-s2", url = "http://localhost:8888/")
public interface S2Api {
    @GetMapping("/v1/s2/dependent-method")
    public String dependentMethod();
}
```

but I get following error, which mean this url was not stubbed.

```
feign.RetryableException: Connection refused: connect executing GET http://localhost:8888/v1/s2/dependent-method
    at feign.FeignException.errorExecuting(FeignException.java:213) ~[feign-core-10.4.0.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Its possible with `MockRestServiceServer`.

Example:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import static org.springframework.test.web.client.match.MockRestRequestMatchers.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.client.response.MockRestResponseCreators.withSuccess;
import org.springframework.test.web.client.MockRestServiceServer;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.AutoConfigureWebClient;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.RestClientTest;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@RestClientTest(MyRestClient.class)
@AutoConfigureWebClient(registerRestTemplate = true)
public class MyRestClientTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockRestServiceServer server;

    @Test
    public void getInfo() {
        String response = "response";
        server.expect(requestTo("http://localhost:8090" + "/another/service/call"))
            .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
            .andRespond(withSuccess(response,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    }
}
```

Comment: `Could not autowire. No beans of 'MockRestServiceServer' type found.`
and also its not able to recognize `getExpectedRequest` could you please share the import statement

Comment: Hi I am using Junit5 and added the code and response error

Comment: i'm not sure what you are trying to do here. Anyway you are getting that error because your test is not a @RestClientTest. Going through your code, a comment I can make is please make separate test classes for rest-client-tests and mock-mvc-tests. They will not work together.

Comment: I am testing my API (Rest Controller Integration test), I want to test all functions/classes that falls in the code execution context. some time we call other APIs as well (external dependency). I want the context to be loaded for everything related to controller, but mock the calls that go out of the system.

Comment: @PHPAvenger I actually dont understand you

Comment: That is said that I am not able to explain properly, could you please read the question again, I have modified some text. and if it still doesn't make sense, you don't have to respond at all. but thank you for help

Comment: @PHPAvenger Since your problem is not much straight forward, can you join with me via skype id: hsupunw ? Im happy to help you

Comment: @SupunWijerathne The question asked a Test with FeignClient implementation, and not with restTemplate. Is there a way for this too? Thanks